# Effects to use for wrapping impure methods?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz, effects, scala-cats

I'm trying to understand how to use effect monads (`cats.effect.IO` or `scalaz.IO` does not matter). Imagine I have the following method:

```
def extract(str: String): String = {
    if(str.contains("123"))
        "123"
    else
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Boom!")
}
```

Since this method is impure (throws exception) and I need to combine its result with another effectful computation (network-IO) is it a good practice to just wrap it into `IO` as follows:

```
def extract(str: String): IO[String] = IO {
    if(str.contains("123"))
        "123"
    else
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Boom!")
}
```

Is it a common use case of Effect monads?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether this is appropriate or not depends on what you want to express.

It's not like your first `def extract(str: String): String`-method definition is somehow invalid: you are just sweeping all the exceptions and side-effects under the rug, so that they aren't visible in the signature. If this is irrelevant for your current project, and if it's acceptable that a program simply crashes with a long stack trace of the thrown exception, then do it, no problem (it's easy to imagine one-off throw-away scripts where this would be appropriate).

If instead you declare `def extract(str: String): IO[String] = IO { ... }`, then you at least can see in the signature that the function `extract` can do something impure (throw an exception, in this case). Now the question becomes: *who is responsible for dealing with this exception*, or *where do you want to deal with this exception*? Consider this: if the exception is thrown, it will emerge in your code in the line where something like `yourProgram.unsafeRunSync()` is invoked. Does it make sense to deal with this exception there? Maybe it does, maybe it doesn't: nobody can tell you. If you just want to catch the exception at the top level in your `main`, log it, and `exit`, then it's appropriate.

However, if you want to deal with the exception immediately, you have better options. For example, if you are writing a method that prompts for a file name, then tries to `extract` something from this name, and finally does some `IO` on files, then the return type `IO[String]` might be too opaque. You might want to use some other monad instead (`Option`, `Either`, `Try` etc.) to represent the failed extraction. For example, if you use `Option[String]` as return type, you no longer have to deal with an obscure exception thousand miles away in your `main` method, but instead you can deal with it immediately, and, for example, prompt for a new file name repeatedly.

The whole exercise is somewhat similar to coming up with a strategy how to deal with exceptions in general, only here you are expressing it explicitly in the type signatures of your methods.

Comment: Understood. Thanks a lot.